# Automate installation of msodbcsql with puppet

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, puppet

To install msodbcsql that comes with mssql-tools that are needed to use the PHP Microsoft SQL Driver for Linux the following command is needed

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
```

However when installing this with Puppet, this fails, the puppet code currently used

```
package { 'mssql-tools'      : ensure => latest, }
```

But this returns an error:

```
ERROR: The EULA was not accepted. Installation aborted.
```

What would be needed so Puppet can successfully install this package. 
I already tried setting a environment variable before calling the package command.

```
Exec { environment => [ "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" ] }
```

Microsoft's installation instructions are here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/02/04/odbc-driver-13-1-for-linux-released/

And this is the driverpage:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/

Comment: When doing sudo apt-get install mssql-tools a ncurses window pops up with two boxes, Yes and No, the default selected is No. So I don't know how to use the responsefile from package to correctly select the Yes field and press enter, backspace tab and the arrow keys can put the selected field on yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this is a feature that was requested; Run the package entity with an environment value.

But since there is a feature freeze this will not be implemented in puppet 4.x (https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6400)

The workaround is to not use the package entity but the exec entity:

```
exec { "/usr/bin/apt-get -yq install msodbcsql":
  environment => "ACCEPT_EULA=Y",
  unless => "/usr/bin/dpkg -l msodbcsql | tail -1 | grep ^ii",
}
```

Where unless is used to make it idempotent to not run if the package is already installed.

Disadvantage of this method is that this only works when using apt-get if you would want this to work on other systems as well you should provide an `$osfamily` with if statement to use the correct package manager.